# Como saber cuantos registros hay en una tabla en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas una llamada accesosprueba1 y la otra cecprueba2.

En la tabla accesosprueba1 tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla cecprueba2 los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo usuario es el numero de usuario que se le da a un empleado ese es unico,
Lo que quiero es saber es cuantos usuarios hay en la tabla accesosprueba, pero buscando su respectivo cec en la tabla cecprueba2, un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir ejemplo: el usuario 10 se muestra dos veces en la tabla accesosprueba1 entonces al hacer la consulta seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando un count, pero no entiendo como complementarlo, alguna idea de como seria? se los agradecería mucho.

Cabe aclarar que en mi tabla accesosprueba1 el usuario 50 es el mismo cec de la tabla cecprueba2 del usuario 10, osea el 101, entonces el resultado final seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En resumen lo que quieres es contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un usuario?

Comment: Si el usuario 50 es el mismo cec que el usuario  10, entonces en lugar de 2, seria 3, actualizo mi pregunta para que se vea reflejado esto. @Japv

Comment: Ya lo actualice, lo que quiero saber es cuantos usuarios hay en la tabla accesosprueba1, pero identificando su respectivo cec, ejemplo: el usuario 50 y 10 son el mismo cec 101, entonces como resultado seria 3 , como en mi tabla final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(A.usuario) as Total, B.cec
from accesoprueba1 A
inner join cecprueba2 B
on A.usuario = B.usuario
group by B.cec
```

Juntamos las dos tablas usando la **cláusula inner join** por el **campo usuario**, una vez relacionadas las tablas utilizamos la **cláusula group by** para agrupar los registros por el **campo cec** de la **tabla cecprueba2**, posteriormente en la **cláusula select** utilizamos la **función de agregación count** para contar por cada grupo obtenido de usuarios el total de usuarios, se selecciona también al **campo cec**.

Para ver otro tipo de resultado puedes hacer esta nueva consulta:

```
select count(A.usuario) as Total, B.cec
from accesoprueba1 A
inner join cecprueba2 B
on A.usuario = B.usuario
group by A.usuario, B.cec
```

Solo que aquí agrupas por los **campos** **usuarios y cec**.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me comenta, así es la idea, puse a prueba  su respuesta y funciona, pero el usuario 50 también su cec es 101, entonces en lugar del numero 2 debería ser 3, cierto? seria con un DISTINCT?. Agrego el resultado en mi pregunta para que se vea como mostrar

Comment: @juliofernandez la consulta resolvió tu problema?

Comment: No del todo, pero así es la idea. Lo que quiero es que todos los usuarios que tengan el mismo cec se cuenten, en mi tabla tengo 3 usuarios que son del mismo cec 101, entonces en el resultado final seria 3 en lugar de dos. Me parece que eso me tocara a mi resolver y subo la actualización.

Comment: @juliofernandez revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: @juliofernandez se resolvió?

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho esto y ahora lo comprendo. Me dio el resultado que queria. Si fue resultado. Gracias @japv